# Concat vars on a valuefields in a for cycle without showing the result

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have this page:

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
  $until_he.$i = htmlentities($_POST['until'.$i])
}
?>

<form action="" method...>
<?php
  for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
       ...
       print '<input name="until'.$i.'" id="until'.$i.'" class="textinput" value="'.$until_he.$i.'" type="date" min="'.date("Y-m-d").'"/>';
       ...
  }
?>
...
```

Now:

```
$until_he
```

has content only once the form is posted, otherwise it's empty. On the other hand

```
$i
```

is already defined.
So as I load the page I get values 1, 2, 3 on the fields.

I'd like to get values on the files only once the user post the forum.
As I load the page the fields should be empty.

Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to do again?

Comment: I improved the question. Hope you can understand me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
   $until_he.$i = htmlentities($_POST['until'.$i]);
   $fieldValue = (trim($until_he.$i)==$i)?"":$until_he;
   ...     
   print '<input name="until'.$i.'" 
                 id="until'.$i.'" 
                 class="textinput" 
                 value="'.$fieldValue.'" 
                 type="date" min="'.date("Y-m-d").'"/>';
   ...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to accomplish and other code you have. In your example, you should use isset($until_he) which doesn't generate a warning if the variable is not set. Also, it works in the case the variable $until_he is set but empty. However, it will fail if you initialize $until_he to an empty value beforehand.

Comment: I improved the question. I hope it's clear now what I'm trying to achieve